# How to speed up Django filter statement

Tags: python, django, filter

I have some django codes as following.I am just filtering different objects and try to get the total number of the fitler results. And then pass these numbers to the html page.
In the html page I just display these total numbers. That's all.

However, when user accesses this page, the speed is really slow. I can't see any improvements in the code which can speed up the programme.
Does anyone have any suggestions on the codes to speed up or all I can do is to upgrade the server?

I was thinking of creating a view or index of these tables in the database. However I have no ideals of how to doing it in django. I also can do it in the database directly, but how can I access the view in the database from django?

```
try:       
    p_r = P.objects.get(p_id=rec_id, f__f_id=f_id, d__n=d)
    s = S.objects.get(r=p_r)
except S.DoesNotExist:
    s = None
except S.MultipleObjectsReturned:
    s = S.objects.filter(r=p_r)


try:
    b = B.objects.filter(r=p_r)
except B.DoesNotExist:
    b = None

bu = {}
if b != None and len(b) > 0:
    bu['count'] = len(b)

try:
    a = A.objects.filter(r=p_r)
except A.DoesNotExist:
    a = None

 an = {}
if a != None and len(a) > 0:
    an['count'] = len(a)


try:
    ar = AR.objects.filter(r=p_r)
except AR.DoesNotExist:
    ar = None

ad = {}
if ar != None and len(ar) > 0:
    ad['count'] = len(ar)




try:
    c = C.objects.filter(r=p_r)
except C.DoesNotExist:
    c = None

co ={}
if c != None and len(c) > 0:
    co['count'] = len(c)



try:
    p_e = []
    ev = E.objects.all()
    for e in ev:
      if e.r_o.p_id == rec_id and e.r_o.record.f.f_id == f_id:
      patient_events.append(e)
except E.DoesNotExist:
    ev = None


ph = {}
if p_e and len(p_e) > 0:
    ph['count'] = len(p_e)
Log().add(request, "View", "I", 'pr', p_r.id)
response_dict.update ({'record': p_r,
                     'summary': s,
                     'bu': bu,
                     'an': an,
                     'ad': ad,
                     'co': co,
                     'ph': ph,
                     'p_id': rec_id,
                     'f_id': f_id,
                     'd': d_id,
                     })
return render_to_response('records/detail.html',response_dict, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: `filter` method won't raise a `DoesNotExist` exception but return an empty QuerySet instead

Comment: Will this try catch thing slow down the speed?

Comment: I posted an answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I could noticed from your code:

1. From my comment, you don't need to use a `try` block when using the `filter` method because  it will return an empty `QuerySet` and will not raise a `DoesNotExist` exception. You could replace blocks like this:

   ```
   try:
       b = B.objects.filter(r=p_r)
   except B.DoesNotExist:
       b = None
   ```

   With just:

   ```
   b = B.objects.filter(r=p_r)
   ```
2. If you want to count the objects of a `QuerySet`, the `count()` method is what you want. So you can replace block like this in your code:

   ```
   try:
       b = B.objects.filter(r=p_r)
   except B.DoesNotExist:
       b = None

   bu = {}
   if b != None and len(b) > 0:
       bu['count'] = len(b)
   ```

   With just:

   ```
   b = B.objects.filter(r=p_r).count() # Will return 0 or more
   ```
3. Seems like models `A`, `AR`, `B`, `C` and `S` have a relation to your `P` model, so you are better off just using the related sets in your template. In fact, perhaps you should be using [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to avoid extra database hits
4. Maybe you can just get the `P` object and use its related objects inside your template to show the counts. In your view:

   ```
   p_r = P.objects.select_related().get(p_id=rec_id, f__f_id=f_id, d__n=d)
   ```

   In your template:

   ```
   <p>A quantity: {{ record.A_set.all.count }}</p>
   <p>B quantity: {{ record.B_set.all.count }}</p>
   <p>C quantity: {{ record.C_set.all.count }}</p>
   ....
   ```
5. In this part of your code:

   ```
   try:
       p_e = []
       ev = E.objects.all()
       for e in ev:
         if e.r_o.p_id == rec_id and e.r_o.record.f.f_id == f_id:
         patient_events.append(e)
   except E.DoesNotExist:
       ev = None
   ```

   You don't need the for loop, you can only use `filter` method for this (sorry if I'm doing it wrong but you get the idea):

   ```
   p_e = E.objects.filter(r_o__p__id=rec_id, r_o__record__f__f__id=f_id)
   ```

Having all this in mind, this might look like a second version of your code:

```
p_r = P.objects.select_related().get(p_id=rec_id, f__f_id=f_id, d__n=d)
ph = E.objects.filter(r_o__p__id=rec_id, r_o__record__f__f__id=f_id).count()

Log().add(request, "View", "I", 'pr', p_r.id)
response_dict.update ({'record': p_r,
                     'ph': ph,
                     'p_id': rec_id,
                     'f_id': f_id,
                     'd': d_id,
                     })
return render_to_response('records/detail.html',response_dict, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: @JiayiZhou take a look at the [Related Object Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/)

Comment: Thank you for your help. But my p model has no field related to A, AR, B, C and S. On the contrary,A, AR, B, C and S have a foreign field related to p. I don't think record.A_set.all.count will work.  And for the r_o field, it is a generic.GenericForeignKey, I don't think I can do as your said.Am I right?